# how to keep looking for incoming sockets in python?

Tags: python

Is there any way for a python script using the `socket` module to keep looking for incoming sockets? For example, if I receive a socket from another pc then it will run this code?

Comment: In a normal TCP server, you call `bind` and `listen`, and that sets things up.  You then call `accept` to accept a new connection.  You can always start a thread to handle that socket, and go back to call `accept` again, which will wait for another connection.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.